# Removing "(Eastern Standard Time)" from javascript date

Tags: javascript, date

I have this function

```
//--format ISO8601 date into sections
function formatDate(date){
    var a = date.split(/[T]/);
    var d = a[0].split("-"); // date 
    var t = a[1].split(":"); // time
    t[2] = t[2].split("-"); // Remove Time zone offset 
    var formattedDate = new Date(d[0],(d[1]-1),d[2],t[0],t[1],t[2][0]);
    //formattedDate.replace(/ *\([^()]*\) */g, "");
    return formattedDate;
}
```

which returns a date that looks like this

> Tue Jan 15 2013 11:07:14 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

I want to remove the (Eastern Standard Time) part. I tried doing formattedDate.replace, but it won't work because I believe it isn't a String.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

My desired output is

> Tue Jan 15 2013 11:07:14 GMT-0500

Comment: Might I recommend http://momentjs.com/ library?  Very small, very effective.  Not a direct answer to your question, so I'm just submitting it as a comment.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: You could change this date to a string using toString(), or ""+formatredDate but the right way would be to format it yourself.

Comment: Use [.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) to convert to a string, then replace or substring to get rid of the EST.

Comment: You could use the Date() get methods to get your format

Comment: Actually, you can't remove anything from `Date` object - it will have different representations depending on how you convert it to text. Convert it to string first, and then strip off time zone.

Comment: I added my expected output, I thought my regexp would get what I wanted but it doesn't...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you return is a `Date` instance. When you output it (by logging it etc), it is converted into a string. So what you want is `.toString()` and then use string functions:

```
var str = formattedDate.toString();

// this should be safe since nothing else in the date string contains a opening paren
var index = str.indexOf(" (");

// if the index exists
if(~index) {
  str = str.substr(0, index);
}
```